# Cannot create redis client (authentication against Cluster)

Tags: python-3.x, redis

Unable to connect to redis cluster using username/password.

`from redis.cluster import RedisCluster, ClusterNode`

```
def get_redis_connection():
  url = f"rediss://{uname}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/0"
  connection = RedisCluster.from_url(url)
  if connection.ping():
     print("Success")
  else:
     print("Failed")
```

> Error occurred in get_redis_connection: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Note: Password contains alphanumeric and special characters, including quotes.
Setup: pip install redis

Assume, user name and password is like below, where username is "travel-tire":

```
rediss://travel-tire:v'Y:[4o2n:3*s@hostname:port
```

Comment: I thinks you need to check 'port' value first.

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: @lunalcni - the port is correct, it's a 4 digit value, have printed all parameters and they appear fine:

Comment: @Irfan434 - it's the from_url(...)

Comment: That error is coming from `int(port)` [in the from_url code](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/search?q=int%28port&type=), and implies that your port is not just a 4 digit int, but contains other non-numeric characters.

Comment: @ZacAnger - Is there a way to escape the :  and [ that's within the password?

Answer (score 2):

You have characters in your password that aren't valid URI components.

```py
from redis.cluster import RedisCluster, ClusterNode
# add this import
from urllib.parse import quote


def get_redis_connection():
    # encode your password to make it valid for a uri
    password = quote(passwd, safe="")
    url = f"rediss://{uname}:{passwd}@{password}:{port}/0"
    connection = RedisCluster.from_url(url)
    if connection.ping():
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

Depending on your version of the Redis client (if you're on a version older than 4.0.0) you'll also need to change the from_url call:

```py
    connection = RedisCluster.from_url(url, decode_components=True)
```